# How do I accept just the column names of a table and then feed into another table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, subquery

```
SELECT (SELECT SC.NAME COLUMN_NAMES FROM 
SYS.TABLES ST INNER JOIN SYS.COLUMNS SC
ON ST.OBJECT_ID=SC.OBJECT_ID
WHERE ST.NAME = 'EMP_TABLE') 
INTO FINAL_TABLE FROM EMP_TABLE SRC 
INNER JOIN HIST_TABLE TMP
ON SRC.ID=TMP.ID AND SRC.UPDATEDATE=TMP.UPDATEDATE
WHERE UID>@UID and UID<=@UID + @BATCHSIZE;
```

Will the query that I have written work? I get confused in matters of subqueries.
Please help me out.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to move the sub query to the `FROM` and give it an instead of `INTO` use `AS` to give it an alias

Comment: Then what do i put in after select? and into is used to insert output(i.e. columns) of subquery into final_table

Comment: OK start at the beginning: what's your data and what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create an empty table with the columns of a user table just execute the query :

```
SELECT SRC.*
INTO   FINAL_TABLE
FROM   EMP_TABLE SRC
WHERE  1 = 2
```

Comment: There are many table and i'm trying to create a dynamic query. So EMP_TABLE is just one of those many tables and hence the reason why I'm using system tables to get the column names by dynamically passing the table names. Once i have received the column names, they should be used as in first select statement and then inserted into final_table

Comment: You can use dynamic sql to do so

Comment: That's where I'm stuck, I'm new to this.

Comment: with cte AS
(
  SELECT SC.NAME COLUMN_NAMES FROM 
SYS.TABLES ST INNER JOIN SYS.COLUMNS SC
ON ST.OBJECT_ID=SC.OBJECT_ID
WHERE ST.NAME = '@TABLENAME'
 )
 
 select cte.* 
 into FINAL_TABLE from cte


WILL SOMETHING LIKE THIS WORK?

Comment: @Shreya . . . This is a much better solution for creating an empty table because it preserves the types.  You have not explained what your code should be doing.  You might want to ask a *new* question with appropriate explanation.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
Select * INTO NewTable
From (
select
   syscolumns.name as [Column]
from 
   sysobjects 
inner join 
   syscolumns on sysobjects.id = syscolumns.id
where sysobjects.xtype = 'u'
and   sysobjects.name = 'Employee') t
```